# Jquery datepicker - setDate not working as part of initialization but works as standalone command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the JQuery datepicker with a set of parameters 
All parameters are working at init time except the setDate.

SetDate also works right after, when given as a standalone command.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Why does setdate not work as part or init in this case?

```js
var maxDateSelectable = new Date(2017, 10, 1);
var minDateSelectable = new Date(2017, 1, 1);
var fromDate = new Date(2017, 9, 12);
$("#WorkingDate").datepicker({
  maxDate: maxDateSelectable,
  minDate: minDateSelectable,
  //setDate: fromDate, //does not work
  beforeShowDay: noWeekends
}); // ~fromDate
//Works here why?
$("#WorkingDate").datepicker("setDate", fromDate);

function noWeekends(date) {
  var noWeekend = window.$.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
  return noWeekend;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='WorkingDate'>
```

Corresponding jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Jersey_Guy/gkymd2hw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `setDate` property for the initial settings object, it's **only** used as a method to set the date at a later time, and that's why it's not working.

If you want to set an initial date, you do so by setting the inputs value, or by calling the `setDate` method on the already initialized datepicker, or by using the [`defaultDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) setting

```
$("#WorkingDate").datepicker({
  maxDate       : maxDateSelectable,
  minDate       : minDateSelectable,
  beforeShowDay : noWeekends
}).datepicker("setDate", fromDate);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks! On a side note, was able to use setDate but not defaultDate the puzzle still remains on the defaultDate way of setting the date :(

Comment: The `defaultDate` doesn't seem to set the date in the input, it just sets the "default selected" date when the datepicker is opened, so probably not what you're looking for